# Custom option of product not display in product view page?

Tags: custom-options, product-view, magento1.9.2.4

I am using magento 1.9.2.4. version. I added some custom option for my test product. 
[Please check this screen short](http://prntscr.com/dw6z4z)

But it's not showing in product view page

I also use this code in view.phtml

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load(1742);
$i = 1;
echo 'kkkk';
foreach ($productCollection->getOptions() as $value) {
echo "<strong>Custom Option:" . $i . "</strong><br/>";
echo "Custom Option TYPE: " . $value->getType() . "<br/>";
echo "Custom Option TITLE: " . $value->getTitle() . "<br/>";
echo "Custom Option Values: <br/>";
// Getting Values if it has option values, case of select,dropdown,radio,multiselect
$values = $value->getValues();
foreach ($values as $values) {
print_r($values->getData());
}
$i++;
}
```

and this also

```
echo '<pre>';
if($product->hasOptions()) 
                        {
    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
        $optionType = $o->getType();
        echo 'Type = '.$optionType;

        if ($optionType == 'drop_down') {
            $values = $o->getValues();

            foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
                print_r($v);
            }
        }
        else {
            print_r($o);
        }
    }    
}
echo '</pre>';
```

But nothing is happened.
And the same code is working fine on xmapp.
please guide me. I am new in magento.

Comment: by default, magento display custom options, no need to use any code.... check the `qty` , make sure its more than `0` also check  `in-stock` is set , also check product by switching to other themes like default, blank.....

Comment: I check it again. product is in stoke and qty is 50. product are display fine and to cart properly. Please suggest the me what i do next dear@BabyinMagento

Comment: please check by switching to different themes under `Design >  Custom Design`

Comment: please share the product url so we check and guide you

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in Product detail page.

```
    $_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
    foreach($product->getOptions() as $option) {
        if ($option->getTitle() == "test") {
            foreach($option->getValues() as $value) {
                Mage::log($value->getPrice(), null, 'price.log');
            }
        }
    }
```

In if condition I have filtered by title name. The same way you can filter and you can get your values